# Padding issue when floating elements inside container

Tags: html, css, css-float, padding

I'm trying to add vertical space between some sections of a page by adding a bottom padding to the section containers, but I can't get it to work. I assume that it has something to do with the fact that I've got un-ordered lists inside the containers and that the list items are floating (using `float: left;`).

I have also tried with margins and what not, but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating your containers left, as well, and then adding bottom margins should fix it

```
#developers, #contributors, #playtesters
{
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I also found out that you can fix this by specifying the height of the UL's within the container DIV's. Though, this is not the best solution if you're planning on updating them and adding new list items, as you'ld have to change the height all the time. So, again, Thank you for the answer. Works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 6):

Either float the containers left or set overflow to "auto." With either solution you will still need to set a margin to create the aforementioned spacing.

```
#developers, #contributors, #playtester {
  overflow:auto;
}
```